# What should be the operation name for creating a monitor alert using terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-monitor

I am trying to create 2 alerts for a VM when it gets

1. deleted
2. powered off

I know that I have to use the below code for creating alerts based on operations but can't figure out what should be the operation name and category:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert" "main" {
  name                = "example-activitylogalert"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  scopes              = [azurerm_resource_group.main.id]
  description         = "description"

  criteria {
    resource_id    = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
    operation_name = "??"
    category= "??"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Category should be always `Administrative` for these operations and as for the Operation names  for the first one you should use `"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/delete"` and the other one `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/PowerOff/Action`.

**Note:** If you are not sure on what operations to be used you can go to the activity and create a alert from portal for a reference.

**Reference:**

[Create, view, and manage activity log alerts in Azure Monitor - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-activity-log#create-an-alert-rule-from-the-azure-monitor-activity-log-blade)